# html Text editor value is not getting saved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to use a text editor in my page.the editor that I have used is
"**Responsive-WYSIWYG-Text-Editor-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-LineControl-Editor**"

This my div tag on which I have applied the text editor and like this I have 5 more div tags with different id's on which I have used this editor

```
 <div rows="" cols="" class="form-control Editor-editor" type="text" id="achievementresponsiblity" detail="industry" indus="indus" placeholder="Responsibilities And Achievements" name="Responsibility"></div>
```

when I am trying to save the content or text written/entered in these divs it's not saving any data. I mean it's not taking the value written in it. Json that I have created for it is as follows

```
    $("#Projectssave").click(function () {
    var remarks = 0;
    jsondata = "";
    if ($('[type="checkbox"][industry="project"]').prop("checked") == true) {
        remarks = 1;
    }
    jsondata += "'ProjectTypeId':'5',"
    jsondata += "'Remark':'" + remarks + "',"
    jsondata += "'Responsibility':'" + $("#achievementresponsiblity").text().replace(/'/g, "&apos;").replace(/"/g, "&Double;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&tg;").replace(/\\/g, "&quot;") + "',";
    $.each($('input[detail="Projects"][type="text"],input[detail="Projects"][type="number"],textarea[detail="Projects"],select[detail="Projects"]'), function () {

        jsondata += "'" + $(this).attr('name') + "':'" + $(this).val().replace(/'/g, "&apos;").replace(/"/g, "&Double;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&tg;").replace(/\\/g, "&quot;") + "',";
    });
    jsondata = jsondata.substr(0, jsondata.length - 1);
    jsondata = '{' + jsondata + '}';
    saveindustrlial(jsondata, $(this).attr("savetype"), "Projects Details");

});
```

but it just save null data in it. I don't know how to deal with it I am done with trying almost everything.

Comment: We need more code, that's not enough. If your `jsondata` is null then there is something wrong with your code that you didn't provide.

Comment: why are you building your JSON object as a string?? You can just make a normal JS object and not have to worry about problems with quote marks etc. If you need to transmit it as a string, you can just run JSON.stringify on the object before you send it. Much more robust. e.g.  something like `var jsondata = {}; jsonData.Responsibility = $("#achievementresponsiblity").text();`

Comment: I have added the jquery code.

Comment: Could you add a link to the editor you used? If it's this one - https://github.com/suyati/line-control - it seems you have to use `$("#placeHolder").Editor("getText");` to get the text.

Comment: Thank you @DanDumitru  it's saving the data successfully. But can you help me with one more issue? when I have to edit the data I am trying it to retrieve in the same editor, but it is not getting its value   this my code to retrieve the data (            $("#achievementresponsiblity").text(sParsedJson[0].Responsibility.replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/&Double;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&tg;/g, ">").replace(/&quot;/g, "\\"));
)

Comment: @KanchanSharma - See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some documentation about the LineControl editor here: https://github.com/suyati/line-control

To get the text from the editor:

```
$("#achievementresponsiblity").Editor("getText");
```

To set the text in the editor:

```
$("#achievementresponsiblity").Editor("setText", "Your text value");
```